# Disable future dates in Angular 8+

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-datepicker

```
<input type="date" class="form-control date-picker" id="date2" name="date" data-date-format="DD MMMM YYYY" [min]="" ngModel required placeholder="DOB">
```

I am trying to fade out future dates without a library in Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try using:**

```js
const datepicker = document.getElementById('date');
const today = new Date();
let date = today.getDate() > 9 ? today.getDate() : 
   `0${today.getDate()}`;
let month = today.getMonth() > 9 ? today.getMonth() + 1 : 
   `0${today.getMonth() + 1}`;
let year = today.getFullYear();

datepicker.setAttribute('max', `${year}-${month}-${date}`);

console.log(datepicker);
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date" name="bday">
```